# Import pandas with graphics disabled

Tags: python, pandas, graphics, xserver, sungridengine

I'm running an analysis using the Sun Grid Engine.

However, in my code I import pandas, which causes this error to be raised:

```
import pandas as pd
```

> : cannot connect to X server :3026.0

What I've gathered from some Googling and conversations with my sys admin is that `pandas` is trying to load graphics, and the SGE is not allowing this.

I don't want to do any plotting with `pandas`.  I just want to use its `DataFrame` features.

Is there a way to load `pandas` with graphics disabled, so the SGE doesn't hiccup in this way?

**UPDATE:** I reverted to `pandas` version 0.18, and that version does not cause this error.  Version 0.20 does cause the error.  I don't have time to investigate exactly which version introduced the error.  But I did post this as an issue on the `pandas` GitHub issue tracker, so hopefully someone else will do the work that remains to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pandas` team told me that this bug should be fixed as of version 0.20.2.

If you are compelled to use versions of `pandas` that contain this bug, one potential workaround is to include

```
export DISPLAY=""
```

at the top of the bash script you submit to SGE.